# Need assistance with PostgreSQL query for hierarchical data retrieval from specified schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Consider the following PostgreSQL database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE manufacturing_process (
    id              bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    process_type    manufacturing_process_type NOT NULL,
    name            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE manufacturing_process_group (
    record_id       bigserial UNIQUE,
    group_id        bigint NOT NULL,
    title           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_id       bigint,
    child_ids       bigint[],
    expansion_type  manufacturing_process_expansion_type NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES manufacturing_process(id)
);
```

Here are the sample data sets for the mentioned tables:

**manufacturing_process (mp):**

```markdown
+----+---------------+------+
| id | process_type  | name |
+----+---------------+------+
|  1 | manufacturing | m1   |
|  2 | manufacturing | m2   |
|  3 | manufacturing | m3   |
|  4 | manufacturing | m4   |
|  5 | manufacturing | m5   |
|  6 | manufacturing | m6   |
|  7 | packaging     | m7   |
|  8 | manufacturing | m8   |
|  9 | manufacturing | m9   |
| 10 | manufacturing | m10  |
| 11 | manufacturing | m11  |
| 13 | packaging     | m13  |
+----+---------------+------+
```

**manufacturing_process_group (mpg):**

```markdown
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
| id | group_id |      title       | parent_id | child_ids | expansion_type |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 | Group 1          | NULL      | {2,3,4}   | checkbox       |
|  2 |        1 | Subgroup 1.1     | 4         | {5,6}     | radio          |
|  3 |        1 | Subgroup 1.1.1   | 5         | {8,9}     | radio          |
|  4 |        1 | Subgroup 1.1.1.1 | 8         | {10,11}   | radio          |
+----+----------+------------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

I am trying to formulate a query that will provide the expected hierarchical order of the data as shown below for a given `group_id`:

**Expected Result:**

```markdown
+-------+---------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
| mp.id | mp.name | parent_id |    mpg.title     | mpg.expansion_type |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
|     0 | null    | null      | Group 1          | checkbox           |
|     2 | m2      | 0         | null             | null               |
|     3 | m3      | 0         | null             | null               |
|     4 | m4      | 0         | Subgroup 1.1     | radio              |
|     5 | m5      | 4         | Subgroup 1.1.1   | radio              |
|     6 | m6      | 4         | null             | null               |
|     8 | m8      | 5         | Subgroup 1.1.1.1 | radio              |
|     9 | m9      | 5         | null             | null               |
|    10 | m10     | 8         | null             | null               |
|    11 | m11     | 8         | null             | null               |
+-------+---------+-----------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Could you please assist me in writing the appropriate query for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Then update your question replacing the images with text. A good place to create text is [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).  Also adding a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful.

Comment: @Akil Vohra posted  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in the subquery, `manufacturing_process.id` rows are selected whose values correspond to the values from the `child_ids` array.
A full outer join is applied: FULL OUTER JOIN according to the condition `mp.id = mpg.parent_id`.

All code from table creation to fetching is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_bIxTHJ_)

```
SELECT COALESCE(mp.id, 0) AS id, mp.name, mp.parent_id, mpg.title, mpg.expansion_type 
FROM
(
SELECT  id, name, COALESCE(parent_id, 0) AS parent_id
FROM manufacturing_process_group, manufacturing_process
WHERE manufacturing_process.id = ANY(child_ids)
) AS mp
FULL OUTER JOIN
manufacturing_process_group AS mpg
ON
mp.id = mpg.parent_id
ORDER BY id
;
```

Output:

```
 id | name | parent_id |      title       | expansion_type
----+------+-----------+------------------+----------------
  0 |      |           | Group 1          | checkbox
  2 | m2   |         0 |                  |
  3 | m3   |         0 |                  |
  4 | m4   |         0 | Subgroup 1.1     | radio
  5 | m5   |         4 | Subgroup 1.1.1   | radio
  6 | m6   |         4 |                  |
  8 | m8   |         5 | Subgroup 1.1.1.1 | radio
  9 | m9   |         5 |                  |
 10 | m10  |         8 |                  |
 11 | m11  |         8 |                  |
```